# Executing a process on a remote machine with Sysinternals PsExec

Tags: asp.net, process, psexec

I'm working on an ASP.NET\C# application.

I'm trying to execute a process in a remote machine using system.Diagnostics.process and Sysinternals PsExec.

Here's my code example:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("psexec");

startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, @"\\machineNAme c:\someDir\Command.exe");
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

Process process = new Process();
StreamReader reader = null;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Command.exe is just a simple test to open cd crive. This code works on a web app on localhost but not on my webapp that is currently on iis.

What am I missing?
tks

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a process in a remote machine using this web based tool [ASN Active Directory Network Manager](http://www.adsysnet.com/asn-active-directory-network-monitor-features.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Permissions. You cannot control that hardware from a web app. Possibly an ActiveX control.